# Strange behavior in MongoDb large collection

Tags: mongodb

Today I had a super weird issue that I couldn't fix for a couple of hours. It was pretty simple but it involved a huge collection so every time I tried to query using a filter I got stuck for 15 minutes with no answer. I know what's the problem but I would like to understand why Mongo behaves in that way.

My collection is around 50 million records. It's indexed only in one record, datetime, so we can rapidly get the time period to analyze and then we extract data. Our analysis can involve in between 20 thousands to 1 million records.

As I use a lot of aggregations my mistake was that in the filter clause I added a $ symbol to one field name.

Instead of:

```
db.collection.find({field:{$gte:...},...})
```

I wrote:

```
db.collection.find({$field:{$gte:...},...})
```

Running db.currentOp() in both cases looks exactly the same, no difference, except for $field instead of field, seems to be doing the same operation. But the one with the wrong $ symbol never ends and never fails.

I'm curious about what MongoDB is trying to do in this case and why it turns into a blocked query that never finishes.

Comment: it is most likely a bug within the field aggregation class since `$` normally relates to a literal field name, it could be running into a loop or something on that

Comment: I could be that it's just trying to find documents with this `$field` field name. Since you don't have this field and no index on it obviously and your collection is very large it takes long time. I could be also a bug as @Sammaye pointed out. You can run `explain()` to see what it's trying to do.

Comment: I will try to to run explain but I think it won't work due to explain runs the query. I agree it could be a bug but also my collection is big enough to cause any kind of troubles finding a field or thinks like that.

Comment: I run an explain for a looooong time and yes, it just scans the whole collection not finding anything neither doing anything. I'm wondering why, find() function doesn't use $ markers and they're not allowed I think. They make sense in an aggregation not in a normal field query.

Comment: Oh I misread, I thought you were using aggregation, I think it is cos you use the word a lot

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that because I use a lot of aggregations in my code, so I mispelled the field name adding a $.